# Jquery click function change between 3 classes. Why not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, icons

I have a code in javascript (w jquery) where the icon when clicked should change between 3 icons from volume up to down to off and again up down off, im thinking and resarching about this but none of things i try to work out seem to work please help. (the code is in $(document).ready).

```
var sound = 0;
  $('.sound').click(function(){
    var sound = sound + 1;
    if(sound == 1) {
      $('.sound').removeClass('glyphicon-volume-up');
      $('.sound').addClass('glyphicon-volume-down');
    } else if (sound == 2) {
      $('.sound').removeClass('glyphicon-volume-down');
      $('.sound').addClass('glyphicon-volume-off');
    } else if (sound == 3) {
      $('.sound').removeClass('glyphicon-volume-off');
      $('.sound').addClass('glyphicon-volume-up');
      var sound = 0;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something simple like this using an array

```js
var sound = 0,
  cla = ['glyphicon-volume-up', 'glyphicon-volume-down', 'glyphicon-volume-off'];
$('.sound').click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass(cla[sound % 3])
    .addClass(cla[++sound % 3]);
  sound = sound % 3;
});
```

```css
.glyphicon-volume-up {
  color: red;
}
.glyphicon-volume-down {
  color: green;
}
.glyphicon-volume-off {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sound glyphicon-volume-up">Button</div>
```

Comment: This rouns an error (the error aplies to the "0, class") someone below sended me piece of code that works but thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a counter, you can use the [`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) method:

```
$('.sound').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass('glyphicon-volume-up')) {
        $this.removeClass('glyphicon-volume-up').addClass('glyphicon-volume-down');

    } else if ($this.hasClass('glyphicon-volume-down')) {
        $this.removeClass('glyphicon-volume-down').addClass('glyphicon-volume-off');

    } else if ($this.hasClass('glyphicon-volume-off')) {
        $this.removeClass('glyphicon-volume-off').addClass('glyphicon-volume-up');
    }
});
```

---

To simplify the code, you can also use the [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) method:

```
        $this.toggleClass('glyphicon-volume-up glyphicon-volume-down');
```

It will remove existing classes and add the missing classes.

Comment: This works perfectly really thank you :D, im still learning to code and this did not even get into my mind :3

Comment: Great, don't forget to accept an answer ;)

You can also use `toggleClass` to simplify the code, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `var sound`

```
var sound = 0;
  $('.sound').click(function(){
    sound++;
    if(sound == 1) {
      $('.sound').removeClass('glyphicon-volume-up');
      $('.sound').addClass('glyphicon-volume-down');
    } else if (sound == 2) {
      $('.sound').removeClass('glyphicon-volume-down');
      $('.sound').addClass('glyphicon-volume-off');
    } else if (sound == 3) {
      $('.sound').removeClass('glyphicon-volume-off');
      $('.sound').addClass('glyphicon-volume-up');
      var sound = 0;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `var` from **starting of function** and from **last else if**. It is already defined above click function else your code working fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var sound = 0;
        $('.sound').click(function(){
            sound = sound + 1;  // sound variable is already defined so no need to define again.
            if(sound == 1) {
              $('.sound').removeClass('glyphicon-volume-up');
              $('.sound').addClass('glyphicon-volume-down');
          } else if (sound == 2) {
              $('.sound').removeClass('glyphicon-volume-down');
              $('.sound').addClass('glyphicon-volume-off');
          } else if (sound == 3) {
              $('.sound').removeClass('glyphicon-volume-off');
              $('.sound').addClass('glyphicon-volume-up');
              sound = 0; // Same as above, no need to define
          }
      });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <button class="sound">Main1</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `var sound = sound + 1;` to `sound = (sound) % 3 + 1`